# Cannot call reset() after response has been committed

Tags: java, servlet-filters

Getting this error while I am trying to reset the Response through **doFilter** method by creating a new servlet **Filter**

Any idea how this can be resolved?

All I wanted is to completely set new response through this Filter.

Comment: `All I wanted is to completely set new response through this Filter` - error is telling you that response can't be reset because it's committed (went out to client). There is nothing you can do about it at this point.

Comment: paste your code and stack trace

Comment: Hi @Vamsi, I am facing same issue. Did you find solution?